# Show PHTML-file in CMS page is not working

Tags: magento2, phtml

I'm trying to call a phtml file in a CMS Page and I know that there are several question for exactly that question already on Stackexchange. The problem is: its not working. I can't get it to running so obviously I'm doing something wrong right now.

This is my theme structure:
**app/design/fronend/MX/base/**

The desired phtml file is here:
**app/design/fronend/MX/base/MX_Slider/template/carousel.phtml**

In my CMS Page I use the following: **{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="MX" template="MX_base::MX_Slider/template/carousel.phtml"}}**

However, the phtml is not showing on the page.

Any ideas why? What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

**custom file path(Based on your theme you can change it)**

```
app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/test.phtml
```

calling in `xml layout` file

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"/>
```

calling in `blocks and cms pages`

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"}}
```

calling in any `phtml` file

```
<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml')) ?>
```

OR
as before

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: Nothing changes - theres no output. Right now I only have Lorem Ipsum content in carousel.phtml, do I need to put anything special in there? Also, I already have read the link you've posted. I tried the code from there but I have a problem setting the path in template correctly... Somehow the  shortcut doesn't work!

Comment: File is calling or not

Comment: No, there is no output on the page. Is there another way to check if "the file is calling or not" - im not sure how this is meant.

Comment: Your Theme name

Comment: In the theme.xml it's defined as "MX CC". Not really sure if this is what you want to know

Comment: here you need to add theme name template="MX_base

Comment: Can you update your answer accordingly? Also, please describe it with 2 or 3 sentences, because I'm still not very sure what exactly you are advising here - if you can explain it in your answer, I'll mark ur answer as the correct one if it works.

Comment: Update my answer based on your theme you can edit your end

Answer (score 0):

use following code in your cms page:-

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="MX" template="MX_Slider::carousel.phtml"}}
```